# Editing Photos for Experiment

Tags: photo-editing, resolution

I have very little experience with images so please bare with me. I need to create 3 different levels of image resolutions for an experiment (i.e low (kind of fuzzy looking), medium, high (original looking photo), conditions). The experiment will be taking place online, so I need the image size to be 700 X 400 to fit onto the web-program that I am using. Where would you suggest I edit my photos (and what would I be editing really) in order to create 3 resolution variations of the same image?

Comment: This question is much clearer than your previous one. Normally on this site you just edit the original question instead of posting a new one to avoid clutter. Perhaps you should just delete the original one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a professional I have access to Photoshop, so in this answer I use that, but you could use the same approach in a free alternative like [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/).

Here we have an image in 700 × 400 px:

[image]

Then we first scale the image down to half size, 350 × 200 px using *Automatic* interpolation:

[image]

With this result:

[image]

And then we scale it up to the original size using *Nearest Neighbor* interpolation:

[image]

The result is this image which has the same size, but 1/4 of the information:

[image]

If we instead scale it down to 25% size and then scale it up to 400% we get this:

[image]

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I'm looking for :) Thank you!

Comment: @annatn998 Of note.. this does *not* take into account KB.. which was the primary hang up in the previous question. `:)`